# Using Kivy screens, how do I change the label from screen 2 based on the pressed button's text on screen 1?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using 2 files with this process, the first being `main.py` and the second `ScreenManagement.kv` I've tried so many different "solutions" from Stack and other sites but nothing is working for me. I want to be able to click a button, and the button will take me to the next screen but also set the label in that screen to the text of the button from the first screen.

I labeled the button, label, and screens in question with comments. Thank you in advance for your help as this has been an ongoing problem :)

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker
from py.fileImport import readMachine
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file("kv/ScreenManagement.kv")

class MainOverview(Screen): #This is the first screen in question
    selectedMachine = StringProperty("")
class MachineStatusPage(Screen): #This is the second screen in question
    selectedMachine = StringProperty("test")
class AddMachinePage(Screen):
    pass
class AddJobPage(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):   

    def build(self):
        
        self.root = root = ScreenManager()
        root.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)
        screen1 = MainOverview(name='MainOverview')
        screen2 = MachineStatusPage(name='MachineStatusPage')
        screen3 = AddMachinePage(name='AddMachinePage')
        screen4 = AddJobPage(name='AddJobPage')
        root.add_widget(screen1)
        root.add_widget(screen2)
        root.add_widget(screen3)
        root.add_widget(screen4)
        

        with root.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 1, 1, .6)  # colors range from 0-1 not 0-255
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=root.size, pos=root.pos)
        return root

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

ScreenManagement.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

<AnchorGridCell@AnchorLayout>:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'
<SubmitButton@Button>:
    text: 'Submit'
    font_size: self.width / 8
    size_hint: .4, .1
<CancelButton@Button>:
    text: 'Cancel'
    font_size: self.width / 8
    size_hint: .4, .1
<MachineButton@Button>:
    font_size: self.width / 20
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'center'
<MachineStatusButton@Button>:
    font_size: self.width / 9
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'center'
    size_hint: .3, .06
<XButton@Button>:
    text: 'X'
    size_hint: None, None
<InputLabel@Label>:
    font_size: self.width / 8
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'center'
<OutputLabel@Label>:
    font_size: self.width / 8
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'center'
<TextCollection@TextInput>:
    multiline: False
    size_hint: 1, .7
    font_size: self.width / 7
    
<ScreenManager>
    transition: NoTransition()
    MainOverview:
        id: mainOverview
    MachineStatusPage:
        selectedMachine: mainOverview.selectedMachine
<MainOverview>:
    FloatLayout:
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                row_force_default: True
                row_default_height: self.width / 13
                padding: self.width / 15
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'center'
                    anchor_y: 'bottom'
                    Label:
                        text: 'All Currently Added Machines'
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: self.width / 16
                        halign: 'center'
                        valign: 'bottom'
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'center'
                    anchor_y: 'top'
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        row_force_default: True
                        row_default_height: self.width / 8
                        col_default_width: self.width / 4
                        padding: self.width / 25
                        spacing: self.width / 25, self.width / 50
                        AnchorGridCell:

###############################################################################

                            MachineButton: #This button is the one in question
                                id: machine1
                                text: "Tsugami 5"
                                on_press: root.selectedMachine = machine1.text; root.manager.current = 'MachineStatusPage'

###############################################################################

                        AnchorGridCell:
                            MachineButton:
                                text: 'Tsugami 6'
                                on_press: root.manager.current = 'MachineStatusPage'
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            MachineButton:
                                text: 'Tsugami 7'
                                on_press: root.manager.current = 'MachineStatusPage'
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            MachineButton:
                                text: 'Tsugami 8'
                                on_press: root.manager.current = 'MachineStatusPage'
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                MachineButton:
                    text: 'Add New Machine'
                    font_size: self.width / 8
                    size_hint: .4, .1
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'AddMachinePage'
                                    
                                
<MachineStatusPage>:
    FloatLayout:
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                rows: 2
                row_force_default: True
                row_default_height: self.width / 13
                padding: self.width / 8
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'center'
                    anchor_y: 'bottom'

#####################################################################

                    Label: #This label is the label in question
                        id: selectedMachine
                        text: root.selectedMachine
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: self.width / 12
                        halign: 'center'
                        valign: 'bottom'

#####################################################################

                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'center'
                    anchor_y: 'top'
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 2
                        row_force_default: True
                        row_default_height: self.width / 8
                        col_default_width: self.width / 4
                        padding: self.width / 25
                        spacing: self.width / 25, self.width / 50
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            InputLabel:
                                text: 'Current Job: '
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            OutputLabel:
                                text: '414-44-1'
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            InputLabel:
                                text: 'Parts Left: '
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            OutputLabel:
                                text: '250'
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            InputLabel:
                                text: 'Time Left: '
                        AnchorGridCell:
                            OutputLabel:
                                text: '3 Days'
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                Button:
                    text: 'Go Back'
                    font_size: self.width / 8
                    size_hint: .4, .1
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'MainOverview'
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                Button:
                    text: 'Add New Job'
                    font_size: self.width / 8
                    size_hint: .4, .1
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'AddJobPage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method [`get_screen`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current_screen) or attr. [`current_screen`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen) to access any screen added to `ScreenManager` (your `root` widget) as,

```py
                            MachineButton: #This button is the one in question
                                id: machine1
                                text: "Tsugami 5"
                                on_press:
                                    root.manager.current = 'MachineStatusPage'
                                    root.manager.current_screen.selectedMachine = self.text
                                    # Or,
                                    # root.manager.get_screen('MachineStatusPage').selectedMachine = self.text
```

Also I think you don't need the following lines of code as you already defined the `root` in method `build`.

```py
<ScreenManager> # Naming dynamic class with default class name is discouraged.
    transition: NoTransition()
    MainOverview:
        id: mainOverview
    MachineStatusPage:
        selectedMachine: mainOverview.selectedMachine
```

Comment: How would I define the transition in the python file in the build method?

Comment: Just pass it as a value for the kwarg `transition` of `ScreenManager` as, `transition = NoTransition()`.